# Multiple matches following a match

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to ask this question, which is probably why I haven't been able to find a solution yet. Hoping this explanation can get me on the right track.

I have strings with a word (Strong, Weak, Moderate) followed by one or more letter/number combinations. For example:

```
Weak: B44,45; C5

Moderate: DR1201,13,14,17,18; DP+; B44
```

I'm interested in capturing only the word and the letters. So for the first line I'd like to get "Weak","B","C",

and the second line would be "Moderate","DR","DP","B"

The following simple regex:

```
\b(A|B|C|DP|DQ|DR)
```

Captures the letters portion perfectly, however when I prepend the words:

```
(Strong|Weak|Moderate).*(A|B|C|DP|DQ|DR)
```

Only the last letter on each line is captured. I realize this is the greedy nature of regular expressions. Making it a lazy match captures the first letter on each line. But is there any way to get it to capture the word and **all** of the letters on each line? I can't help but think I'm missing something, just can't figure it out.

Comment: Good catch. Second line should just contain "B" without its numbers. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
(Strong|Weak|Moderate)(?:.*?\b(A|B|C|DP|DQ|DR))+
```

The first group will include the `Strong`, `Weak`, or `Moderate`. The second group will contain multiple captures, one for each letter that was found. The non-greedy quantifier here is required to make sure that it doesn't swallow up any other characters between the first and second group. For example:

```
var input = @"
Weak: B44,45; C5
Moderate: DR1201,13,14,17,18; DP+; B44";
var pattern = @"(Strong|Weak|Moderate)(?:.*?\b(A|B|C|DP|DQ|DR))+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach(Match m in matches) {
    Console.Write("{0}: ", m.Groups[1].Value);
    foreach(Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures) {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", c.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Will produce the following output:

```
Weak: B, C,  
Moderate: DR, DP, B,
```

Comment: That looks pretty much exactly like I was hoping. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could match all letters:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+
```

You should get an array of all the letters.

`\b` ensures that there is no other letter or number before it (or underscore, since it's part of the `\w` class).

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xE9vP5)

In code:

```
string input = @"
Weak: B44,45; C5

Moderate: DR1201,13,14,17,18; DP+; B44
";
string[] lines = input.Split(new Char [] {'\n'});
var reg = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

/// Using RegexOptions.IgnoreCase lets you use [A-Z]+ just the same way as
/// [A-Za-z]+

foreach (String line in lines)
{
    if (line == "")
    {
        continue;
    }
    var words = reg.Matches(line)
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Value)
                   .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", words.ToArray()));
}
```

Output:

```
Weak, B, C
Moderate, DR, DP, B
```

[demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/kY1ToZ)

Answer (score -2):

Question isn't clear... but this may help:

```
\b[a-zA-z]+\.[a-zA-z]+
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer of what this does and how it answers the question. *Especially* if you find the question unclear, it's important to explain what your code is intended to accomplish. (FYI, I'm encountering this as a Low Quality Posts review.)